# ActionScript3. The screen auto change after a time

Tags: actionscript-3, frame, keycode

I'm newbie in AS3 and have a stuck while coding pause and un-pause.
At the frame 20

```
    stage.frameRate=0;
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, wait);
function wait(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
        if(event.keyCode == 40)
        {
            //Resume pause by return framerate = 20
            stage.frameRate = 20;
            event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,wait);
        }
}
```

I dont' know why after wait about 10 second, this screen contain this code automatic change to frame 21

Comment: Delete your `stage.framerate` and replace it by the **adapted** code : `gotoAndStop(20)`

Answer (score 0):

**frameRate's value**

Adobe help mentions that [0 can't be the frameRate's value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate):

`Valid range for the frame rate is from 0.01 to 1000 frames per second.`

That means that for a frameRate's value of 0.01, your Flash movie will play 100 seconds later.

**gotoAndStop()**

The stage frameRate's property is not intended to stop your movie at a frame, but to get and set the frame rate of the stage.

If you want to `stop` your Flash movie and wait frame 20:

```
gotoAndStop(20);
```

If you want to `play`:

```
play();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but gotoAndStop was not affect. It's can't stop at frame 20.

Comment: @XuanRoyal You just have to delete stage.frameRate from your code, and add `gotoAndStop(20);` to the wait function.